# Waze - open waze.to links in app and start navigation,

Tags: android, ios, waze

I would like to open the Waze app from a web browser but the links I have in my db are in this format:

- http://waze.to/li/hsv9hc540y
- https://waze.to/li/hsv8v8wv81

When I click on these links from my mobile web browser they open the app but the navigation doesn't begin, it's only opens the app and that's it.

After reading the [updated waze api](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/) I haven't found a way to navigate using the encrypted string 
 **`hsv9hc540y`** 
 only by latitude and longitude which I don't have.

How can I convert those waze.to links to the new deep links api using the encrypted string I have so it will open the app and init navigation?

Comment: what happend if you do this ? https://www.waze.com/ul?q=sv8wrg7c5 instead of the url you are passing now ? because as the doc says To search for an address and then navigate to that address: you need to use ul?q=

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your deep links are not correct. To make them work, they need to look like this:

- https://waze.com/ul/hsv9hc540y
- https://waze.com/ul/hsv8v8wv81

For more info, check this link:
https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Comment: thats right, i was aware to post it as an aswer because i dont know too much about waze haha, but thats correct

Comment: is the same to use this ?  waze.com/ul?q=sv8wrg7c5  as the link ? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid not. This deep-link form is for search, where q is the search term. Passing this hash code is essentially telling waze to search for some gibberish.

Comment: @GilMoshayof thank you Gil,  When `waze.to` was obsolete?

Comment: You're very welcome! The waze.to form became obsolete about a year ago (more or less). The /ul/ form (stands for Universal Link) will lead the user to a Waze web page if Waze is not installed on the device.

Comment: Also though - waze.to links should still work (but not for long) - just without an additional path symbol: "http://waze.to/hsv9hc540y"

Comment: @GilMoshayof it would be nice if you tell your friends to add this to waze deep links documentation.

Comment: @GilMoshayof I'm trying to use waze navigation from iOS app. I don't have long/lat, only address and I can't make it work. I try `"waze://?q=30+Ibn+Gabirol+St.+Tel+aviv,+Israel"` with no luck. It opens Waze, but doesn't navigate... Help?

Comment: How do you generate the shortened link? The documentation in https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/ only provides long links.

Comment: how to pass parameters to avoid highways/tolls/ferries ?

Comment: I want to know if is it any way possible to add multiple directions in the same link?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
            // Launch Waze
            String mapRequest = "https://waze.com/ul?q=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude + "&navigate=yes&zoom=17";
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(mapRequest);
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.waze");
            startActivity(mapIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
            {
            // If Waze is not installed, open it in Google Play
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.waze"));
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: please refer link: https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/#navigate-to-location